# Pytorch tensor reshape 2d to 3d without loosing data

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, reshape

i need convert pytorch 2D tensor to 3D,
suppose `x` is(`torch.Size([16, 1024]`)) and need to convert `torch.Size([16, 1024, 1024])` by copying reshaping tensor without loosing `x` data.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be by expanding dimension and repeating its elements

```
x_3D = x.unsqueeze(2)
x_3D = x_3D.repeat(1,1,1024).reshape(16,1024,1024)
```

checking if the elements are the same and at the same position

```
torch.all(x[0,:] == xt_expand[0,0,:])
```